# Should we use yeoman generator-ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, yeoman

It has been first time I use [generator-ionic](https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic) for building an ionic project (before just `ionic start myApp blank`) and it has been disappointing.

I ran:

```
mkdir ionic-generator-test && cd $_
yo ionic
npm install && bower install
grunt serve
```

After few minutes browser opens and on the console I found:

> Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable Module 'starter' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument.

Problem is that app.js file is not loaded. Path in HTML file is wrong:

```
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Should be

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Such simple and big error and last update of the generator was on Dec 29, 2015 (commit c5eb207).

Do you think ionic-generator is reliable?

Answer (score 0):

ionic-generator is a well known and used Yeoman Template. Another popular template is [generator-m-ionic](http://github.com/mwaylabs/generator-m-ionic), which uses Gulp and has regular updates.

On the [git hub page](https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic), it looks like generator-ionic is not receiving many upddates.